# Reading picture from eID, having trouble displaying it on webpage

Tags: php, image, yii2

We are implementing the Belgian eID Identity Provider in a web application. It all works great until we tried to show the returned picture. The documentation says the returned string should be `base64_decoded` before sending to the browser. However doing so results in a 'broken' image.

Printing the string directly in the `src` attribute of an `img` tag does not seem to work either.

Could someone point us in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

The string: 
`_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAgE3[...]V9XjlXKMGHtS7aaRnvSAAVXuL2C3H7yQA-nU1h6jq5nBSIbUPfuayScnJNH1o704d6XIHev_Z`

The code from the docs:

```
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
session_start();
// echo decoded image payload
echo base64_decode($_SESSION["imagedata"]); 
// imagedata holds the above string
// results in browser error message 'image could not be loaded' when visiting directly
```

Since we are using Yii2 this should be action like:

```
$response = Yii::$app->getResponse();
$response->format = Response::FORMAT_RAW;
$response->data = Yii::$app->session["imagedata"];
$response->headers->set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
//$response->headers->set("Content-Encoding", "base64"); ??

// echo decoded image payload
return Yii::$app->response;
```

One of many other attempts:

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,[string]"> <!-- resulted in 0x0 'image' -->
```

---

EDIT:
Turns out it has something to do with Yii2 sanitizing the response in authClient. Anyone knows how to disable this for certain values?

Comment: Can you tag the example image please? That way we can look into whether it's encoding right

Comment: looks like the base64 of image is not proper, try with another image

Comment: It's definitely the base64 string it's not an image

Comment: Hm, thing is, this is the string I get from the ID card. If I use the card with a eID viewer, it shows the picture fine. Any chance this is another kind of encoding?

Answer (score 1):

In your code I see `$response->headers->set("Content-Type", "image/png");` and the docs says `jpeg` so I think you should change that to `image/jpeg`. You are mixing the wrong image forms which is probably causing it to display wrong. If this doesn't work make sure your image in not messed up or corrupt in someway. You can use [this](http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter) to test your image.

Comment: I tested your image with the tool I linked and it doesn't display. This might just be your image unless you just gave us an example image, and if you did you better edit the question before you confuse some more people.

Comment: With testing I forgot to change it back to 'jpeg'... Thought it was wrong in docs.

Comment: Found out what is wrong with the string. It is Yii2 sanitizing the response values. '/' got replaced with '_' and '+' with '-'.

Comment: @Brainfeeder Nice! Good luck on the rest of your project! Upvote? ;)